# Generate DB schema and load data based on XML file?

Tags: xml, oracle, database-schema

We have a large XML file with lots of data relationships and lots of data.  Is there a way to generate a DB schema based on the relationships and then load the data into the schema?

Answer (score 1):

Just write an XSLT which would generate schema in SQL.
Then write another XSLT which would generate INSERT statements.

Answer (score 0):

Stuff like this can be found on the Oracle OTN XMLDB Forum. This one is mentioned here: [Generate XML Schema from oracle tables](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1515908)